# IOS - Swift - Core Data - Loading the values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using the CoreData for the first time and
I have done the work to save the values from [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_Core_Data_Tutorial) tutorial and ewerything works fine.

i created the .swift file with all the function to save the state for the particular object. the values cold be "on" or "off" with its self on or off functions.

there is how the values are saving:

```
func objectON()
{
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Groops", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let Groop = Groops(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    Groop.object = "on"

    var error: NSError?
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
    if let err = error {
        println(err.localizedFailureReason)
    }
}
```

but i have a trouble with loading the data. the tutorial version is realy uncomfortable to use in my situation.

will be good if i create the single function that will returne the value on or off in the same .swift file with saving functions. and may look like this

```
func loadValue(object: String) -> String {
   var value = "loadedValue"
   return value
}
```

so i just can use the `if returnedValue == "on" { code }`

can someone help me with tis function?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial what you are using have solution for you, it's under "Retrieving Data from the Persistent Store using Core Data ".

You just have to fetch your data from persistent store. Then you can make whatever you want with your data.

```
let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let moc = appDel.managedObjectContext!

let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Groops")

var error: NSError?

let results = moc.executeFetchRequest(req, error: &error) as! [Groops]

if results.count > 0 {
    println("I have my saved data and I can do something now")
}
```

And if you want filter your data with fetchrequest, take a look how predicate's work.

Comment: Thanks, I have done the function and there another problemm appeares. when i loading the value for key it works only if it is the first key in Groops.swift and .xcdatamodeld. and others are giving the error "found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"